# Columns and rows in bootstrap Grid System not working properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive

I am trying to implement a grid system using Bootstrap-3. I am using rows and cols, but not all columns are behaving properly as you can see in the following snippet.

```css
.pink{
  background: pink;
}

.yellow{
  background: yellow;
}

.gray{
  background: gray;
}

.blue{
  background: blue;
}

.green{
  background: green;
}

.red{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 ">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 pink">test</div>
            <div class="col-md-12 yellow">test</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 gray">
        test
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 ">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 blue">test</div>
            <div class="col-md-6 green">test</div>
            <div class="col-md-6 red">test</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 green">test</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 pink">test</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 gray">test</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is my targeted design:
[image]

I am using bootstrap^3.3.7 in angular 2 project.
**EDIT:**
After updating my code and adding images, I got the following design:
[image]
As you can see, in the first row, **pink** and **blue** cols are not of the same height, as well as the **pink** col in the second row.
Why is this happening?

Comment: I didn't get your problem. The link and code you gave have the same UI. Can you please tell what is the expected and actual result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They way you are nesting `col-*` inside another `col-*` is not what bootstrap suggests to do. You should not immediately next `col-*` inside another parent `col-*`. What bootstrap suggests is, you should always have `<div class="row">` as immediate parent while using any `col-*`

Here is solution to your problem

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 ">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 pink">test</div>
                <div class="col-md-12 yellow">test</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 gray">test</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 ">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 blue">test</div>
                <div class="col-md-6 green">test</div>
                <div class="col-md-6 red">test</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 green">test</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 pink">test</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 gray">test</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have another another issue now, I'll update my question so you can see it.

Comment: You need to have same size for all the images that you are using. About the images that go into col-6, you need to make it relatively same height. OR, you can wrap every image in an individual div and assign height to the div along with overflow:hidden. This would solve your issue.